# Plot two graphs in same plot in R and MarkDown, I have problem with the past answers

Tags: r, plot, graph, line, par

I would like to plot cc and cc2 in the same plot. In my Markdown sheet

I have tried these solutions. From the answer of other users.

````
---
title: "MWS"
output: html_document
---

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
pp<-seq(from =1 , to =10)
cc<- rep(1,10)
cc2<- cos(0.5*cc) 
#first try
plot(pp,cc)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(pp,cc2)

#second try

plot(pp,cc,type="l")
lines(pp,cc2)
plot(pressure)
```
````

In the first case, my error is
"calling par(new=TRUE) with no plot"

In the second case my error is
"Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) :
plot.new has not been called yet"

I have also tried the third try

[image: This is the error message with an almost empty MarkDown sheet]

On the third try, the error is the same.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. I get the expected output. If you restart a new session, generate your data, then call `plot(pp, cc)` do you get a plot? If so, calling `lines(pp, cc2)` should add lines to your plot.

Comment: @AllanCameron In a new session I get the expected output. In the current session, I am working in markdow. I edit my question. With Markdown the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases it's best not to use high-level plotting functions, like `plot()`, at all. Instead, try:

```
pp  <- seq(from=1, to=10)
cc  <- rep(1, 10)
cc2 <- cos(0.5*cc)

plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=range(pp), ylim=range(cc, cc2))

lines(pp, cc,  col=1)
lines(pp, cc2, col=2)
```

Comment: Is it working in markdown?
My error persists "Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : plot.new has not been called yet
"

Comment: Try this: 1) If you are using R-studio - restart it; 2) delete everything from your markdown except the proposed code; 3) try running it again; 4) hopefully you shouldn't get the same error.

Comment: I tried that and the error persists (Check the image attached in the question)...I update it to show that if I delete everything from my markdown the error persists.

Comment: OK, this is a bit weird. Can you try to render your markdown without R-studio? Open R in the console and run `rmarkdown::render("your_script_name.Rmd")` ?

Comment: When you talk about the console, you mean 'the terminal of my computer" or the console that is in R studio? I am trying to find a way to open the document from the terminal.

Comment: I would try doing it separately from R-studio, so that R-studio doesn't hijack the plotting device. Just open console (command line) on your computer, enter "R", press enter, and then run the script to render the markdown file.